# Without extension can I add configurable product to cart?

Tags: configurable-product, cart, simple-product

I have Magento 1.7 and whenever I add a configurable product to cart it instead adds the simple parent product with the simple product price as well. I've read a bunch of posts with people doing the opposite if possible I would want to do this without an extension.  Anyone else have a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a misunderstanding, there is no such thing as a "simple parent product" . If you don't use any extensions for configurable products (like "Simple Configurable Products" or "Better Configurable Products"), adding configurables to cart works like this:

- technically, two items are added to the cart:

  1. the configurable product itself, as **parent item**

     - the configuration is saved as custom option
     - the price is determined based on configurable product price + option price
     - **this is the item you see in the cart**
  2. the selected simple product, as **child item**

     - this item is not visible in the cart
- when placing the order, **stock** is decreased for the **child item**.

If there's still something unclear, please update the question with more details what you expect or what you don't understand.